# Arrays giving error when trying to echo

Tags: php, arrays

I have a huge array, in which i want to display the specific parts of it.

I have a part of it, here:

```
["dagskema"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Mandag (14/8)"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["noter"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(30) "16:10-17:35  KOR i AVLSGÃ…RDEN"
      }
      ["fag"]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(17) "2d re â€‹JH â€‹04"
          ["note"]=>
          string(365) "14/8-2017 09:05 til 09:55 Hold: 2d re LÃ¦rer: Jens Christian von Holck (JH) Lokale: 04  Lektier: - Medbring en oplevelse fra sommerferien, hvor du pÃ¥ en eller anden mÃ¥de har vÃ¦ret i forbindelse/ vidne til/ tÃ¦nkt over noget religiÃ¸st. Uddybning: Du skal kunne formidle din oplevelse via fÃ¥ stikord eller en enkelt kort sÃ¦tning (skal kunne bruges anal [...]..."
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(26) "2d SP â€‹BL â€‹01
  intro"
          ["note"]=>
          string(165) "intro 14/8-2017 10:05 til 10:55 Hold: 2d SP LÃ¦rer: Bjarke Ledskov (BL) Lokale: 01  Note: vi skal repetere materialet fra sidste Ã¥r og snakke om hvad vi skal i Ã¥r."
        }
        [2]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(17) "2d SP â€‹BL â€‹01"
          ["note"]=>
          string(76) "14/8-2017 11:00 til 11:50 Hold: 2d SP LÃ¦rer: Bjarke Ledskov (BL) Lokale: 01"
        }
        [3]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(17) "2d Sa â€‹FS â€‹03"
          ["note"]=>
          string(283) "14/8-2017 12:30 til 13:20 Hold: 2d Sa LÃ¦rer: Freja Schloss (FS) Lokale: 03  Lektier: - Terrorisme pÃ¥ tvÃ¦rs (Hansen & Jensen, side 26-32).pdf [...]  Ã˜vrigt indhold: - Rasmus PÃ¶ckel oprÃ¸rsmodellen.docx [...]  Note: Hvad er terrorisme? Hvordan kan vi prÃ¦cist definere terrorisme?"
        }
        [4]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(17) "2d Sa â€‹FS â€‹03"
          ["note"]=>
          string(359) "14/8-2017 13:25 til 14:15 Hold: 2d Sa LÃ¦rer: Freja Schloss (FS) Lokale: 03  Ã˜vrigt indhold: - Why Russiaâ€™s reaction to the St. Petersburg bombing is all about strengthening Putin's power [...]     (Eksempel pÃ¥ misbrug af ordet "terrorisme". Artikel fra Newsweek, 10. april 2017.)  Note: Hvordan kan begreberne terror/terrorisme/terrorister misbruges?"
        }
        [5]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(17) "2d Ma â€‹Ma â€‹23"
          ["note"]=>
          string(108) "Aflyst! 14/8-2017 14:20 til 15:10 Hold: 2d Ma LÃ¦rer: Malik Lindholdt (Ma) Lokale: 23  Note: Omsorgsdag (Ma)"
        }
        [6]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(17) "2d Ma â€‹Ma â€‹23"
          ["note"]=>
          string(108) "Aflyst! 14/8-2017 15:15 til 16:05 Hold: 2d Ma LÃ¦rer: Malik Lindholdt (Ma) Lokale: 23  Note: Omsorgsdag (Ma)"
        }
        [7]=>
        array(2) {
          ["tekst"]=>
          string(108) "KOR i AVLSGÃ…RDEN 
  Alle 1. G. elever  Alle 2. G. elever  Alle 3. G. elever  KOR 2017-18 â€‹LL â€‹AG1 (mu)"
          ["note"]=>
          string(187) "Ã†ndret! KOR i AVLSGÃ…RDEN 14/8-2017 16:10 til 17:35 Hold: Alle 1. G. elever, Alle 2. G. elever, Alle 3. G. elever, KOR 2017-18 LÃ¦rer: Svend JÃ¸rgen Lyngberg-Larsen (LL) Lokale: AG1 (mu)"
        }
      }
    }
```

I specifically want's to target the "fag" array.

I tried the following, but it returns an error:

```
        <?php
    include("lectio/lectio.php");
        $lectio = new lectio();
        $skemamag = $lectio->get_skema_til_elev(94, 16305782848);
var_dump($skemamag);
?>        
 <div class="skema-lektioner-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($skemamag['dagskema']['Mandag (14/8)']['fag'][8] as $key => $val) {
        echo '<p class="lektioner lektioner-'.$val.'">';
        echo $val;
        echo '</p>';
    }?>
    </div>
```

Error looks like this:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/square-brain.com/itk/index.php on line 62
```

I use the api LectioAPI on github, link [here](https://github.com/HSPDev/lectio)

I specifically use [this](https://github.com/HSPDev/lectio/blob/master/lectio.php) file

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Remove`[8]` from the foreach loop.. Only use `$skemamag['dagskema']['Mandag (14/8)']['fag']`

Comment: `$skemamag['dagskema']['Mandag (14/8)']['fag'][8]`.... this does not exists... `$skemamag['dagskema']['Mandag (14/8)']['fag']` has 8 elements [0-7]

Answer (score 1):

You need to look closer at you array structure. PHP is big on arrays, so you need to become familiar with them

```
<?php 
foreach ($skemamag['dagskema']['Mandag (14/8)']['fag'] as $fag) {
    // $fag is also an array, not sure if you want both of its members
    // or just one
    echo '<p>'
    echo $fag['tekst'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $fag['note'];
    echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

To avoid using the `'Mandag (14/8)'` array by name, as it will probably change over time, you could do

```
<?php 
foreach ($skemamag['dagskema'] as $d => $dag) {
    echo echo "<p>$d</p>";  // echo that dag

    foreach ( $dag['fag'] as $fag) {

    echo '<p>'
        echo $fag['tekst'];
        echo ' ';
        echo $fag['note'];
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can i also take parts of the array string and display? As in string(365), i want to show some part in one place and another in another place

Comment: Yes you can. But as I dont know what you want to do, maybe a new question would be the best way to ask that